# What's the correct way of using the accepts_nested_attributes_for and the build methods for updating record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, crud, nested-attributes

I'm using Rails 4.1.4 on a Xubuntu machine. I have a Question model that has many alternativas (possible answers in my language), like this:

```
# question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :alternativas, dependent: :destroy
  validates_presence_of :text
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :alternativas, reject_if: proc {|attributes| attributes[:texto].blank? }
end

# alternativa.rb
class Alternativa < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Question only has the :text attribute (string), and answer only the :texto attribute (also a string). I can create a question, but when I try to edit it, it edits only the question text, not the answers. New answers are created instead of the old ones being updated.

Also, as the :text field is required, when I leave it blank it redirects to the same page with the error message, but for some weird reason all the answers are doubled (if there is one answer when I submit the form, there will be 2 equal answers when it shows the error message).

So how can I solve this two problems? My guess is that I'm not using the build and the accepts_nested_attributes_for methods correctly, so here is my controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authorize
  before_filter :verify_admin

  def index
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
    @question.alternativas.build # I also tried 5.times { @question.alternativas.build } for 5 answers text fields
  end

  def edit 
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.update(question_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @question.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to questions_url, notice: 'Question was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  def set_question
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:text, { alternativas_attributes: [:texto, :question_id] })
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `question_params`. It should be like below

```
def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:text, alternativas_attributes: [:id, :texto, :question_id])
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution solved my two problems, but now I'm stuck again. Could you please see my edit?

Comment: @Gabriel Instead of posting it as a edit, I recommend you to create another question explaining your problem clearly. In that way you can get answers quickly. And you should accept my answer as it solves the problem to your question.

Comment: OK, I'll create another one. Thanks.